# JSP insert to database with Submit Button

Tags: mysql, jsp, submit

I'm trying to create a **JSP** application which is doing **database insertion**. I should know about how to insert a some data to **MYSQL** database to when I **pressed the submit button** in JSP. and I want to stay on this page after done the process. what should I do?

Thanks you.

Comment: Submit to a *servlet* and use JDBC, and do it with Ajax (to keep from changing the page).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you using a framework such as Struts or Spring?

Chances are you'll want to upload to the database using JDBC within your business logic (not in your JSP).

So, you'll have your input page (JSP) which will do initial validation prior to even reaching your business logic. If initial validation passes, your business logic will run and that's when you should be connecting to your database. If initial validation fails, simply display an error message so the input can be fixed.